# using Group By - what is an appropriate aggregate when trying to match one field against another's MIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

Cannot work out how to complete this query.

I have a series of devices with a communal log. Each device can have events of online, offline and processing. I need to have a count on the number of times a device goes "online then offline" each day without processing anything in this period.
Note: I have no say in the contents of the fields

ie if device comes online then several entries later goes offline and none of those entries are processing for this device, then add one to the count. If one of those entries is a processing, then this set of online/offline shoud not add to the count.

eg

```
Time               Device    Event
1/1/01 10.00.00    1         Online 123
1/1/01 10.01.00    1         Offline 124
1/1/01 10.02.00    2         Online 125
1/1/01 10.03.00    1         Online 126
1/1/01 10.04.00    2         Processing 127
1/1/01 10.05.00    1         Offline 128
2/1/01 10.00.00    2         Offline 129
2/1/01 10.01.00    1         Online 130
2/1/01 10.02.00    2         Online 131
2/1/01 10.03.00    1         Processing 132
2/1/01 10.04.00    2         Processing 133
2/1/01 10.05.00    1         Offline 134

...
```

should give result for device 1 of:

```
2   1/1/01
0   2/1/01
```

The 0 for the 2/1/01 demonstrates that if there is a processing in between Online and Offline, it should be excluded from the count. Note: there could be many processing statements before offline.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT      COUNT(WakeUpTime) AS NonProcessingWakeUpsPerDay
            ,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, WakeUpTime)) AS Day
FROM        (
                SELECT          MIN(DATEDIFF(SECOND, r1.Time, r2.Time)) AS WakeUpTimeSpan
                                ,CASE WHEN r2.Event LIKE 'Offline%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Processed
                                ,r1.Time AS WakeUpTime
                FROM            dbo.Record r1,
                                dbo.Record r2
                WHERE           r1.Device = @Device
                AND             r2.Device = r1.Device
                AND             r2.Time > r1.Time
                AND             r1.Event LIKE 'Online%'
                AND             (r2.Event LIKE 'Offline%' OR r2.Event LIKE 'Processing%')
                GROUP BY        r1.Time
            ) AllWakeups
WHERE       Processed = 0
GROUP BY    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, WakeUpTime))
```

but this has problems in the inner query with the Case statement. I cannot work out how to add an aggregate to this, as I want the value that corresponds to the correct event entry (ie the row pair with the minimum timespan).

Comment: Are you wanting to group by date only, ignoring time?

Comment: Yes, and as there are online offline periods that span a date boundary, the online should be used as the basis for the grouping

Comment: Can you explain your result. What do the 2 and 0 mean? Count of Online>Processing>Offline sequences within the date? Shouldn't 2/1/01 be 1? If not why is it 0?

Comment: Actually I understand your requirement.. but not your query.. why do you self join?

Comment: What is the significance of the "minimum timespan" between a pair? Also it seems you want a count of seconds, but you're also comparing days difference? Could you perhaps state your expected result more clearly?

Comment: @ElectricLlama Count Online>Offline (excluding Online>Processing>Offline or any variation thereof)

Comment: @OracleUser Self join was a result of how I thought of it. Each counted event consists of one row where the device comes online, and another row where the device either processes and is hence excluded from count, or goes offline and is included in the count.

Comment: @TimothyWalters the minimum timespan is because if the device goes up and down many times in the log, I needed a way to join the online to the next event in the table (ie the closest record that happens after the online that concerns this device), otherwise I might be processing mismatching pairs of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see part of your issue, look at the following query:

```
SELECT
  CAST(r1.Time AS DATE) AS DateOnly,
  r1.Time AS StartTime,
  r2.Time AS EndTime,
  DATEDIFF(second, r1.Time, r2.Time) AS EventSeconds,
  r1.Device,
  r1.Event AS StartEvent,
  r2.Event,
  CASE
    WHEN r2.Event LIKE 'Offline%' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS Processed
FROM Record r1
JOIN Record r2
  ON r1.Device = r2.Device
  AND r2.Time > r1.Time
  AND r1.Event LIKE 'Online%'
  AND (
    r2.Event LIKE 'Offline%'
    OR r2.Event LIKE 'Processing%'
  )
WHERE r1.Device = 1
```

For your sample data and just using Device 1 we are getting multiple records for each start time, where I believe you probably only want to match to the next record in time order.

For example "Online 123" is joining to "Offline 124", "Offline 128", "Processing 132" and "Offline 134", but should only join to "Offline 124" (thus wanting the row with the minimum timespan).

Instead you could look at partitioning your data, consider the following:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    r.Time,
    r.Device,
    r.Event,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Device ORDER BY r.Time) AS RowNumber
  FROM @Record r
 )
SELECT r1.Event, r2.Event
FROM cte r1
JOIN cte r2
  ON r1.Device = r2.Device
  AND r2.RowNumber = (r1.RowNumber + 1)
  AND r1.Event LIKE 'Online%'
```

This provides the following output pairs:

```
Online 123  Offline 124
Online 126  Offline 128
Online 130  Processing 132
Online 125  Processing 127
Online 131  Processing 133
```

From this base point of having correct pairs, you can go on to get the actual data you want. Have a look at this:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    r.Time,
    r.Device,
    r.Event,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Device ORDER BY r.Time) AS RowNumber
  FROM Record r
),
byDateCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(r1.Time AS DATE) AS EventDate,
        CASE WHEN r2.Event LIKE 'Processing%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Processed,
        CASE WHEN r2.Event LIKE 'Offline%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UnProcessed
    FROM cte r1
    JOIN cte r2
      ON r1.Device = r2.Device
      AND r2.RowNumber = (r1.RowNumber + 1)
      AND r1.Event LIKE 'Online%'
)
SELECT
    EventDate,
    SUM(Processed) AS Processed,
    SUM(UnProcessed) AS UnProcessed
FROM byDateCTE
GROUP BY EventDate
```

Output:

```
EventDate   Processed  UnProcessed
2001-01-01  1          2
2001-01-02  2          0
```

Comment: thanks. This looks good. I have always struggled with using partitioning correctly. I will accept answer as soon as I verify it works on the actual data.